# matching two data frames and change values in one of the data frames

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames. The reproducible examples are given below:

```
structure(list(`1` = c(0L, 1L, 1L), `2` = c(1L, 0L, -1L), `3` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `4` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `5` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `6` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `7` = c(0L, -1L, 0L), `8` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `9` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `10` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `11` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `12` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `13` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `14` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `15` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `16` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `17` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `18` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `19` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `20` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `21` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `22` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `23` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `24` = c(-1L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

This has 24 columns and each column represent statement.  The second data frame is as follows:

```
structure(list(Level = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Statement = c("attr1", 
"attr2", "attr24", "attr7"), StmtNo = c(1L, 2L, 24L, 7L)), .Names = c("Level", 
"Statement", "StmtNo"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

This 2nd data frame has a column by name StmtNo.  This is the corresponding number for the column in df1.  For e.g.., StmtNo 1 in DF2, matches with column Number 1 of DF1.

What I am trying to do is:

For all the cells with values 0 in DF1, I have to match the column numbers in DF1 with the StmtNo column of DF2.  If the column number matches, the cell value should be 0, if it doesn't match, then the value should be NA.  I tried using apply with if condition:

```
df1 <- apply(df1, function(x) if (x == 0) {
    if (exists(colnames(df1)) %in% df2$StmtNo) {
        x == NA
    } else {
        x == 0
    } 
})
```

But this returns a logical list.  My desired output is as follows:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
3  0  1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA -1
6  1  0 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
12 1 -1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
```

While the above might seem a lot uniform in terms of filled in NA's, I have 60 such files and each with different columns where NA's need to be filled in.

Comment: Do you mean that all the values in `StmtNo` column should be kept as it is in df1 and rest if zeroes should be changed to `NA` ?

Comment: No, the values in df2$StmtNo matches column numbers in df1.  So if the cell value in DF1 for a particular column is Zero, then I need to check if that particular column number is available in df2$StmtNo.  If it is available then I have to leave it as zero, and if it isn't available then I need to change it to NA.  The desired out put that I have given, has NA for Column 3 in DF1.  This means 3 is not available in df2$StmtNo.

Comment: yes, `df2$StmtNo` has values 1, 2, 24, 7 and those columns have retained their values in `df1` and rest all have transformed to `NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less-than-elegant brute force approach

```
cols <- names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% df2$StmtNo]
df <- data.frame( matrix(NA, ncol = length(cols), nrow = 3) )
names(df) <- cols
df <- cbind(df, df1[, df2$StmtNo])

df[, order(as.numeric(names(df)))]

#    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
# 3  0  1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA -1
# 6  1  0 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
# 12 1 -1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
```

Comment: `df1[!names(df1) %in% df2$StmtNo] <- NA` or `replace(df1, !names(df1) %in% df2$StmtNo, NA)` as a simplification.

Comment: Thank you Symbolix.  This is clever!!  I was bogged down by the 60 odd data sets and trying to find solution for all of them in one go...this helps.

Comment: @thelatemail looking at the expected output this seems to be the solution but I feel there is something more that OP wants.

Comment: @RonakShah - maybe `df1[!names(df1)[col(df1)] %in% df2$StmtNo & df1==0] <- NA` then?

Comment: @thelatemail - they are indeed better / more elegant solutions. You should add them as an answer

Comment: @LeArNr you're welcome. However, you should consider thelatemail 's suggestions as they are better than mine

Comment: @Symbolix - added, though the underlying logic is very similar to your answer, hence the +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt using some indexing of a `data.frame` object.
The basic selection returns this:

```
!names(df1)[col(df1)] %in% df2$StmtNo & df1==0
#       1     2    3    4    5    6     7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23    24
#3  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
#6  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
#12 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Which means that you can do:

```
df1[!names(df1)[col(df1)] %in% df2$StmtNo & df1==0] <- NA
df1

#   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
#3  0  1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA -1
#6  1  0 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
#12 1 -1 NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
```